# selectInput in R fetching data from MySql

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I have just started using MySql since couple of days.  Pardon me if this is a very basic query.

I have a table in MySql having four columns: content, media_provider, date and sentimet.  Sentimet has three levels in it viz., pos, neg & neu.

Using a shiny selectInput, I am trying to fetch all the records that are tagged as pos, neg or neu.  The following is the code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            selectInput(inputId = "wafer", label = "Select sentiment", choices = c("pos", "neg", "neu"), 
                        multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = "40%"),

            actionButton("do", "An action button")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("value"),
            verbatimTextOutput("que"),
            verbatimTextOutput("wq_print"),
            dataTableOutput(outputId="post")
        )
    )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$df <- data.frame()

    d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

    output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

    a <- reactive({ paste("SELECT * FROM apparel WHERE sentimet = ", d(), sep="") })

    output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

    observe({
        if (!is.null(d())) {
            wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

            output$wq_print <- renderPrint({ print(str(wq())) })

            values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())
        }
    })

    output$post <- renderDataTable({ values$df })  

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run, I got the following error:

```
Warning: Error in .local: could not run statement: Unknown column 'neg' in 'where clause'
```

I understand MySql considers the 'factor' neg as column 'neg', so I changed my choices option in selectInput from "pos" to 'pos' = 1, MySql looks for value 1, and returns NULL.  I changed 1 = "pos", "pos" = "pos", nothing worked.  However when I directly provide the query in MySql "SELECT * FROM apparel WHERE sentimet = "pos";"  works flawlessly.  Not sure how to use the selectInput.  Providing a 3 line reproducible example below:

```
structure(list(CONTENT = c("@myntra Good Morning If you are born poor its not your mistake, But if you die poor its your mistake. -Bill Gates Good Day", 
"@myntra i have been mailing my issue daily since past week.All i get in reply is an auto generated assurance mail. 1st time pissed wd myntra", 
"@myntra I'm a big Arsenal fan & made a big PUMA collection! ¥Ë_ Shared that collection yesterday. Wanna win... ¥Ë_¥Ë_¥Ë_ #myPUMAcollection"
), MEDIA_PROVIDER = c("TWITTER", "TWITTER", "TWITTER"), PUBLISH_DATE = structure(list(
    sec = c(0, 0, 0), min = c(30L, 22L, 11L), hour = c(7L, 7L, 
    7L), mday = c(21L, 21L, 21L), mon = c(10L, 10L, 10L), year = c(115L, 
    115L, 115L), wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L), yday = c(324L, 324L, 324L
    ), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("IST", "IST", "IST"), 
    gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta"), 
    sentimet = c("neg", "pos", "neu")), .Names = c("CONTENT", 
"MEDIA_PROVIDER", "PUBLISH_DATE", "sentimet"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in your sentimet column are characters so you need to wrap them with single quotes :

`a <- reactive({ paste0("SELECT * FROM apparel WHERE sentimet = '", d(), "'") })`

Comment: Thank you ...this worked!  I tried with double double quotes... """" like in excel.  Thank you again.

Comment: Well, the problem is, if you use double quotes in the `paste0` call, you can't use them to wrap the elements of your sentimet column because otherwise it'll look like this : 
`"SELECT * FROM apparel WHERE sentimet = "pos""`
and R will throw an error because this is not valid syntax. With single quotes, it'll look like this : 
`"SELECT * FROM apparel WHERE sentimet = 'pos'"` 
and this is valid.

Comment: Thank you again.  I am just following the same principle with other widgets...and it is working like a breeze.